# jQuery Clone for showing single image

Tags: jquery, clone

If we select multiple images, how can we show only single image when we are dragging?
when I tried to drag, it was showing all the three selected images appended to it.
As I'm showing the total count on drag images.

My benchmark is Picasa Web Albums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what the name of the class that is applied to items as they are dragged, but I believe it is `ui-draggable-dragging` but you could do something like the following for the start event of the drag.

```
$(".ui-draggable-dragging:gt(0)").hide();
```

This will hide all but the first item. When the drag stop event is fired you should just be able to unhide them again by calling `show()` instead of `hide()` and replacing `.ui-draggable-dragging` by another class they have in common.